# How many digits make sense for cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation

I am currently developing a mathematical symbol classifier (see http://write-math.com) for my bachelors thesis in computer science. To evaluate what type of classifiation / features / parameters work, I calculate from the labeled dataset with $n$ instances of $m$ mathematical symbols the accuracy. I do this by 10-fold cross-validation:

- I divide my labeled dataset into 10 bins (each bin includes roughly the same number of instances per symbol)
- For every bin b:

  - b is the test set, everything else is the training set
  - classify each element in b and compare it with the known label
  - count correct / wrong classifications
- accuracy = $\frac{correct}{correct+wrong} = \frac{correct}{\text{number of instances}}$

I am now wondering to how many digits I should publish the accuracy. I definitely see changes in the first 3 digits / the first 3 digits seem to be constant no matter how I bin.

Is that the way to determine the number of digits? Do the same cross-validation multiple times with "random" bin creation and see which digits are the same?

Should I publish other values than the accuracy, e.g. the variance of the accuracy over the 10 loops?

Comment: For clarity - you are simply asking about how to *present* the results of the accuracy in a table? If that is the case, then I answered a similar question on the [Academia site](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/23142/3) and I would give the same answer here. The Feiberg and Wainer citation suggests to try to limit significant digits to only three numbers in tables.

Comment: @AndyW: Thanks. Yes, this question is about presentation. It might be better placed on Academia.SE than here, but I forgot that Academia.SE existed.